# node.js socket.io listener not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets

I have a chat with private message but the private message doesnt work.
This is the app.js

```js
var express = require('express'),http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
console.log("Hola");
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');

 app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.render('index.jade',{layout:false});
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.logged)
    {
     res.send('Welcome back!');
     console.log("Welcome back!");
    }
    else
    {
        req.session.logged = true;
        res.send('Welcome!');
        console.log("Welcome");
    }
});
server.listen(1080);

function tstamp() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var days = new Array('Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab');
  var day = currentTime.getDay();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (hours > 11) {
    var ap = 'p';
  }
  else {
    var ap = 'a';
  }
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }

  return "["+ days[day] + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ap + "m] ";
}

//websockets
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var usuariosConectados = {};
var usuariosId ={};
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
 socket.on('enviarNombre',function(dato){
  if(usuariosConectados[dato])
   socket.emit('errorName');
  else
   {
    // store the nickname in the socket session for this client
    socket.nickname = dato;
    //console.log("El usuario es: " + dato);
    usuariosConectados[dato] = socket.nickname;
    usuariosId[dato] = socket.id;
   }
   sId = [dato,usuariosId];
   data = [dato,usuariosConectados];
   io.sockets.emit('mensaje',data);
 });
 socket.on('enviarMensaje',function(mensaje){
  var data = [socket.nickname, mensaje];
  io.sockets.emit('newMessage',data);
 });
 socket.on('mensajePrivado',function(targetUser,msg) {
  //console.log(sId[1][targetUser]);
  //console.log(msg);
  //console.log(socket.id);
  console.log(tstamp());
        io.sockets.socket(sId[1][targetUser]).emit('newPrivado', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
        io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('newPrivadoSender', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
   });
 socket.on('disconnect',function(){
  console.log("Entro a disconnect");
  delete usuariosConectados[socket.nickname];
  data = [usuariosConectados,socket.nickname];
  io.sockets.emit('usuarioDesconectado',data);
 });
});
```

The problem is when i use the listener "mensajePrivado" it never get to there and i dont know why. The socket.on('enviarMensaje') listener works fine.

I call it like this:

```js
function sendPrivateMessage (targetUser)
{
 console.log("entro en sendPrivateMessage");
 var privateMsg = $('#'+ targetUser + 'privateMsg').val();
 //verificamos que no tenga scripts
 if((privateMsg.indexOf("<") != -1))
 {
  alert("Mensaje incorrecto");
 }
 else if((privateMsg.indexOf(">") != -1))
 {
  alert("Mensaje incorrecto");
 }
 else if((privateMsg.indexOf(";") != -1))
 {
  alert("Mensaje incorrecto");
 }
 else
 {
  $('#'+ targetUser + 'privateMsg').val("");
  console.log(privateMsg);
  console.log(targetUser);
  websocket.emit('mensajePrivado', targetUser, privateMsg);
 }
}
```

Also when i inspect elements in the Chrome browser i get the following error
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value must contain 'Upgrade'

How can i fix all this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a proxy in front of Node? The error ` 'Connection' header value must contain 'Upgrade'` indicates that you have Apache/Nginx/etc. in front of Node and it isn't setting the appropriate headers for websockets

Comment: I have Nginx in a Plesk Onyx. How can i configure that?

Comment: Read the "Virtual Host Configuration" part of this article: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: nginx is not running on my server. another reason?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was in this part:

```
io.sockets.socket(sId[1][targetUser]).emit('newPrivado', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
    io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('newPrivadoSender', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
```

i replace with this:

```
io.to(sId[1][targetUser]).emit('newPrivado', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
    io.to(socket.id).emit('newPrivadoSender', tstamp(), socket.nickname, targetUser, msg);
```

now it works fine!